What is the fastest possible speed of walking?
Consider a human with 2 thin legs each with mass $m$ and length $L$, and the rest of the body has mass $M$. I want to know what is the fastest speed it may walk, without leaving the ground.
If we analyze the model w.r.t. to the foot staying static on the ground, we see that the angular momentum must come from the leg behind.

Suppose the static leg makes angle $\theta_1$ with the horizontal, the moving leg makes angle $\theta_2$，whose derivatives w.r.t. time are $\omega_1,\omega_2$, then we have its Lagrangian
$$L=T-V=\frac{1}{2}M(L\omega_1)^2+\frac{1}{6}m(L\omega_1)^2+\frac{1}{6}m(L\omega_2)^2-MgL\sin\theta_1-\frac{1}{2}mgL\sin\theta_1-\frac{1}{2}mgL\sin\theta_2$$
Subject to the boundary conditions that both legs are static on ground with starting angle $\theta_0$, and there is some impulse $J$ on the leg behind.
I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Are you sure there is a clear boundary between walking and running ? In both cases foots leaves the ground. They differ only by leg oscillation frequency and transition from walking to running can be very smooth and continuous.

@AgniusVasiliauskas As in race walking, there must be at least one foot on the ground at any moment.

Surely you must introduce some limit on the power that the leg muscles can generate ? Otherwise you could "walk" as fast as you like - although you might need magnetic boots to stop the walk becoming a run.

@gandalf61 the speed limit in this model exactly comes from that the impulse should not be large enough for the person to leave the ground.

The fastest possible speed is surely that of the world record holder.  Physics is an experimental science first and foremost, so the fastest possible speed is that record from a physics point of view.
These individuals work very hard to remove every inefficiency in their motion.  The level of modelling required to analyze purely theoretically is complex.  A simple model, like yours, will fall some considerable way short of modelling the motion of a race walker.
You might notice, for example, the arm motions of such athletes.  These arm motions are precise and not at all accidental, and they are designed to improve balance, motion and efficiency.  Walking is a full body action, not just the legs.

I agree this should be based on experimental evidence. However,1. your statement does not address the record breakers in the future;2. would you like to comment on some certain race-walking strategies from a physics point of view?

@MaYe The first step would be modeling the entire body, especially as StephenG suggests.  Organic bodies are notorious for finding far better solutions than the simplified models of them.

I think you should first define the term "walking" because there are various ways to describe it.  One of the most common definitions, and the one I think you want, is that there is at least one leg in contact with the ground at all times.  [Sorry, I saw the answer in the comments after I wrote this.]
I wrote a paper a long time ago describing a simple model that could be extended to make a first-order approximation.  The contact force on the stance leg was not a focus of interest but it would be relatively simple to calculate and determine the angular speed when it approaches zero.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12887844_The_simplest_walking_model_Stability_complexity_and_scaling
Of course, we would then have to reconsider the assumption of a stiff straight stance leg and a hip that travels in an arc.  If a human could force their hips to move in a horizontal line (and there is no reason to think that they can't) then in theory there would be no velocity limitation due to pendular motion.  The resulting motion would probably look something like a two-legged crab.  Which is not a bad description of racewalking.
But in real life, bipeds transition from walking to running for apparently energetic reasons, not necessarily dynamic limitations.  Walking in such an awkward way as described above, while optimized for a certain outcome, is undoubtedly very inefficient.
http://ruina.org/research/topics/locomotion_and_robotics/why_walk_and_run/Manoj_thesis_FINAL_12pt_singlespaced.pdf
https://manojsrinivasan.org/papers/JTB_2005_Ruina_Bertram_Srinivasan_collisions.pdf
So I guess my final answer is that determining a limit to walking velocity depends on the model, constraints, and assumptions that you use.

Without personal experience or researching the web, from a purely physics standpoint I would think that the maximum walking speed is theoretically primarily limited by two factors: (1) the maximum possible force the walker's leg muscles are capable of pushing back on the ground without both feet leaving the ground (assuming that's a requirement for "walking") and (2) the maximum equal and opposite force, per Newton's 3rd law, the ground is capable of pushing the walker's feet forward without slipping to accelerate the walker between steps.
One could approach this by considering only the second factor, as in the case of an accelerating car. No matter how powerful an engine the car has, it's my understanding that the maximum possible acceleration is limited by the maximum possible static friction force that the road is capable of applying to the car to prevent slipping between the tires and road. That force is, in turn, limited by the maximum possible coefficient of static friction between the road and the tires. And finally that depends on the tires and the road surface.
Similarly, for the walker, perhaps there exists a limit to the force (and thus walker's acceleration) that the ground can exert forward on the walker, regardless of the walkers strength or any other related individual skills, related to the walker's foot wear and/or ground surface conditions.
Hope this helps.
